# How do you pass default values to payload in flask-restplus?

Tags: python, flask, flask-restplus

I am setting up an restplus API, and want some default fields to be passed if the query don't contain these values. How do i pass these using an api model, preferably without the use of requestParser?

As it stands now, the payload doesn't get affected by setting default values, thus making it unnecessary. I have tried making the arguments required, but that is of no use since i want to be able to pass only parts of the expected payload.

```py
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restplus import Api, Resource, fields

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app=app)
model = api.model("simple_model", {'some_bool': fields.Boolean(required=False, default=False),
                                   'some_int': fields.Integer(required=False, default=99)})


@api.route('/foo')
class SomeClass(Resource):

    @api.expect(model)
    def post(self):
        return request.json


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='localhost', port=8000, threaded=False, debug=True)
```

Testing with the code

```py
import requests

query = {"some_bool": True, "some_int": 20}
res = requests.post("http://localhost:8000/foo", json=query)
print(res.json())

query = {"some_bool": True}
res = requests.post("http://localhost:8000/foo", json=query)
print(res.json())

query = {"some_int": 20}
res = requests.post("http://localhost:8000/foo", json=query)
print(res.json())

res = requests.post("http://localhost:8000/foo")
print(res.json())
```

This gives the output

```
{'some_bool': True, 'some_int': 20}

{'some_bool': True}

{'some_int': 20}
None
```

The expected value, and the desired output is

```
{'some_bool': True, 'some_int': 20}

{'some_bool': True, 'some_int': 99}

{'some_bool': False, 'some_int': 20}

{'some_bool': False, 'some_int': 99}
```

All help is appreciated.

### EDIT:

After the answer by @IMCoins, Iended up writing a function that made me able to acces the items inside the function like this

```py
def get_content(api_model):
   @marshal_with(api_model)
   def get_request():
      return request.json
   return get_request()
```

and then just accessing the content inside as

```py
content = get_content(model)
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use the RequestParser ?

Comment: Because the entire api is based off of api.model(..) if there is a simple way to translate the models into RequestParser i will gladly use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand it, if you want to make sure you have all the keys you need at entry point, you need to use `RequestParser()`. `api.expect()` decorator is used to document the swagger.

However, if you want to make sure your request always returns a basic template (something like your model here), you can use the model you created into the decorator `api.marshal_with()`.

For instance, in your examples here, just replace `expect` by `marshal_with` and it will include the missing values in the response.

Comment: api.marshal_with() appear to work as intended when i pass validate=False in "@api.expect". Thank you. 

If api.marshal_with() always return this template, wouldn't that also mean i always have all the keys as RequestParser() would provide?

Comment: I believe you wish to use this data inside the route. For this, you need to use RequestParser. If you want to make sure your route will always return a basic template, you should use marshal_with;

Comment: I made a workaround using marshal_with that seems to work. Check out the edit of the original post

Answer (score 1):

I think without request Parser, it's not possible to get what you want. this default keyword is not actually the answer. because if you try to debug with Logs, it's only receiving which you're passing as query. but then api is not adding the default parameter in missing case, the Required param doesn't work there too. so i guess use it as described above by @IMCoins ?

Comment: I suppose so, but the [docs](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reqparse.html) suggests other libraries such as [marshmallow](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Ideally i would just want a function that took my models as input and got the desired output as RequestParser, but marshal_with() seems to work for now. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

jsonschema actually has a solution for this... but dose not include it in there main library:

https://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq/#why-doesn-t-my-schema-s-default-property-set-the-default-on-my-instance

```
schema = {'some_bool' {'type': 'bool', 'default': 'false'}, 'some_int': {'type': 'number', 'default': 99}}

def post()
   data = request.json
   DefaultValidatingDraft7Validator(schema).validate(data)
   return data
```

Should result in

```py
res = requests.post("http://localhost:8000/foo")
print(res.json())
{'some_bool': False, 'some_int': 99}
```